# Installation of SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

I am installed visual studio 2008 and SQL server management studio.
Now I want to install SharePoint 2013.Please tell me how to install SharePoint

Answer (score 3):

What you did is not considered prerequisites to install SharePoint 2013, 
In general, Visual Studio is not a prerequisite to installing SharePoint and you should use at least Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 with SharePoint 2013.

So I advise you to check first the [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) and make sure that your current environment match at least the minimum requirements in this article.

Then check the installation steps at

- The Microsoft official article [Install and configure SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- or at [SharePoint 2013 - Step-By-Step Installation Guide](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/page/install-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

If you don't need to read and apply you can watch and apply this video [SharePoint 2013 Server Installation Step By Step Full](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u81RqLqWLC8)